# I can't capture all Request errors / exceptions. Something is causing an unkown error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am pinging a web page a number of times using the `Requests` module.

It starts off working perfectly, but about 100 calls in it stops working and every call to the website fails after that. I can't figure it out.

I thought I set it up to capture all possible errors using `except requests.exceptions.RequestException`, but something else is happening that isn't captured by this.

I'm not sure if you need to see the headers but here they are: (there are no cookies or data. Data is inserted in the url string)

```
headers = {}
headers['Host'] = 'www.wensite.ie'
headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/63.0.3368.71'
headers['Sec-Fetch-Mode'] = 'cors'
headers['Sec-Fetch-Site'] = 'same-origin'
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br'
headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
cookies = {}
data = {}
```

And the request. My `except` was set up to capture all errors (i thought?)

```
try:

    data = requests.get(f'https://www.website.com/api/search/name/{firstname}/surname/{surname}/eircode/{zipcode}/lang/en',headers = headers,cookies = cookies,data=data,timeout=5)

    data = data.json()

    if data['results']:
        print('**Record Found**\n\n------------------')
        return 'record found'
    else:
        print('record not found\n\n------------------')
        return 'record not found'

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print('Exception Ecountered....\n')
    print(str(e))
    print('\n------------------')
    return str(e)

except:

    print('Unknown Error Encountered\n------------------')
    return 'Unknown Error'
```

The final `except` is where I'm getting my error messages from. And at around 100 calls, every attempt results in this error. It feels like the website is blocking me. But shouldn't I get a `HTTP 403 error` or something like that?

How can I diagnose this to capture every single possible error?

By the way this is not an official api, I am 'scraping' the website with a pause of 2 seconds between each call.

Comment: If you remove the last except block, the program will terminate, giving you an insight into what exactly the exception is that arises. If you do that and post the stacktrace here, we might be able to help you out further

Comment: @NicoGriffioen OK thanks, i'll do that. By the way, I am not sure if they are blocking me - my IP is not blocked, I can re-start this function at any time. It just fails about 100 calls in. I will return with the stacktrace.

Comment: Turns out it was a `KeyError`. When parsing the `json` response, a key i was indexing didn't exist anymore. On further investigation, it turns out this new `json` had the `http status code 429` which means too many requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle errors of a request not with an exception handler, but by checking the status code instead. You can also try catching the JSON decoder error in case the response content is not a proper JSON object (import `json` first):

```
response = requests.get(f'https://www.website.com/api/search/name/{firstname}/surname/{surname}/eircode/{zipcode}/lang/en', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, timeout=5)
if response.status_code >= 400:
    message = 'Error from server: {} {}'.format(response.status_code, response.reason)
    print(message)
    return message
try:
    data = response.json()
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    message = 'Error decoding response content as JSON: {}'.format(e)
    print(message)
    return message
```

Comment: Turns out it was a `KeyError`. When parsing the `json` response, a key i was indexing didn't exist anymore. On further investigation, it turns out this new `json` had the `http status code 429` which means too many requests. And you are right there was a status code in the json - 429. Too many requests.